# Can I migrate a LUKS partition from a passphrase to a keyfile?

Tags: luks

Let's say I have a LUKS-formatted partition, and it's secured using the passphrase "test123". Can I migrate this partition to a key-based mechanism, without loss of data?

Comment: Rather than migrating, there's nothing wrong with having both (provided a good passphrase, rather than test123). It makes some things easier (such as unlocking from a live/rescue system when the keyfile is unavailable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. LUKS allows you to have multiple keys, so you can add/modify/remove keys as you need. The actual key which is used to access the data is internal and hidden. There is no difference between a plain passphrase, a key in a file or derived keys.

You can add a new passphrase for example with

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey DEVICE FILEWITHPASSPHRASE
```

Then you can test it. If everything works, you can remove your old password with

```
cryptsetup luksRemoveKey DEVICE
```

See the [man page of cryptsetup](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup) for more details.